# Handling checkboxes in nested/hierarchial categories using jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have an online store with WooCommerce, and I'm trying to users correctly choose the categories.

The idea is that if they select a category child, the parent category is selected too.

This I have done, but when uncheck the category child (and there is no input checked) the parent remains checked.

```
$('ul.product_cat_list').find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(index, input) {
  $(input).bind('change', function() {
    var checkbox = $(this);
    var is_checked = $(checkbox).is(':checked');
    if(is_checked) {
        $(checkbox).parents('li').children('input').attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
      $(checkbox).parentsUntil('ul').find('input').removeAttr('checked');
    }
  });
});
```

Here the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/83drcjuy/)

Comment: Try using `.prop('checked', true);` and `.prop('checked', false);`. `checked` is a property as oppose to an attribute.

Comment: These scenarios get complex quickly. You need to factor in the checked state of the siblings as well. And should checking/unchecking a parent check/uncheck all children?

Comment: You missed the great opportunity to wrap both your Titles and chechboxes into that label.

Comment: @j08691 Will consider the siblings. Checking/unchecking a parent check/uncheck all children no is necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at your markup following is the hierarchy:

```
product_cat_list
    li
        input+ul.children
            li
                input+ul.children
                    li
                    li
                    li
                input+ul.children
                    li
                    li
                    input+ul.children
                        li
                        li
                            input+ul.children
                                li
                                li
                                li
                            input+ul.children
                                li
                                    input
                                li
                                    input
                                li
                                    input
                                li
                                    input
                        li
                    li
                input+ul.children
                    li
                    li
                    li
            li
            li
            li

    li
```

I have added few more levels so as to run tests.
After running through tests it is seen that same operation is performed repeatedly from starting point. So you will need a function that is called recursively.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("ul.product_cat_list input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {

        var checkboxValue = $(this).prop("checked");

        //call the recursive function for the first time
        decideParentsValue($(this));

        //Compulsorily apply check value Down in DOM
        $(this).closest("li").find(".children input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", checkboxValue);


      });

      //the recursive function 
      function decideParentsValue(me) {
        var shouldTraverseUp = false;
        var checkedCount = 0;
        var myValue = me.prop("checked");

        //inspect my siblings to decide parents value
        $.each($(me).closest(".children").children('li'), function() {
          var checkbox = $(this).children("input[type=checkbox]");
          if ($(checkbox).prop("checked")) {
            checkedCount = checkedCount + 1;
          }
        });

        //if I am checked and my siblings are also checked do nothing
        //OR
        //if I am unchecked and my any sibling is checked do nothing
        if ((myValue == true && checkedCount == 1) || (myValue == false && checkedCount == 0)) {
          shouldTraverseUp = true;
        }
        if (shouldTraverseUp == true) {
          var inputCheckBox = $(me).closest(".children").siblings("input[type=checkbox]");
          inputCheckBox.prop("checked", me.prop("checked"));
          decideParentsValue(inputCheckBox);
        }

      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="control unstyled product_cat_list">
  <li id="product_cat-51">
    <input value="51" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-51">
    <label class="selectit">Accesorios</label>
    <ul class="children">

      <li id="product_cat-52">
        <input value="52" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-52">
        <label class="selectit">Abanicos</label>
      </li>

      <li id="product_cat-53">
        <input value="53" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-53">
        <label class="selectit">Bandoleras y riñoneras</label>
      </li>

      <li id="product_cat-246">
        <input value="246" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-246">
        <label class="selectit">Billeteras</label>
      </li>

      <li id="product_cat-205">
        <input value="205" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-205">
        <label class="selectit">Botones, pins</label>
      </li>

      <li id="product_cat-54">
        <input value="54" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-54">
        <label class="selectit">Bufandas</label>
      </li>

      <li id="product_cat-342">
        <input value="342" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-342">
        <label class="selectit">Cartucheras</label>
      </li>

      <li id="product_cat-55">
        <input value="55" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-55">
        <label class="selectit">Chales y ponchos</label>
      </li>

      <li id="product_cat-56">
        <input value="56" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-56">
        <label class="selectit">Cinturones</label>
        <ul class="children">

          <li id="product_cat-69">
            <input value="69" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-69">
            <label class="selectit">Cinturones de hombre</label>
          </li>

          <li id="product_cat-70">
            <input value="70" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-70">
            <label class="selectit">Cinturones de mujer</label>
          </li>

          <li id="product_cat-71">
            <input value="71" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-71">
            <label class="selectit">Cinturones infantiles</label>
          </li>

          <li id="product_cat-72">
            <input value="72" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-72">
            <label class="selectit">Cinturones unisex</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li id="product_cat-60">
        <input value="60" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-60">
        <label class="selectit">Estuches, fundas</label>
      </li>

      <li id="product_cat-61">
        <input value="61" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-61">
        <label class="selectit">Gorros, boinas y sombreros</label>
        <ul class="children">

          <li id="product_cat-78">
            <input value="78" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-78">
            <label class="selectit">Gorros y boinas de fiesta</label>
          </li>

          <li id="product_cat-79">
            <input value="79" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-79">
            <label class="selectit">Gorros y boinas de hombre</label>
          </li>

          <li id="product_cat-80">
            <input value="80" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-80">
            <label class="selectit">Gorros y boinas deportivos y de playa</label>
          </li>

          <li id="product_cat-81">
            <input value="81" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-81">
            <label class="selectit">Gorros y boinas infantiles</label>
          </li>

          <li id="product_cat-361">
            <input value="361" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-361">
            <label class="selectit">Gorros y boinas para mujer</label>
          </li>

          <li id="product_cat-83">
            <input value="83" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-83">
            <label class="selectit">Otros</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li id="product_cat-93">
        <input value="93" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-93">
        <label class="selectit">Máscaras</label>
      </li>

      <li id="product_cat-63">
        <input value="63" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-63">
        <label class="selectit">Mochilas</label>
      </li>

      <li id="product_cat-64">
        <input value="64" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-64">
        <label class="selectit">Monederos y estuches</label>
      </li>

      <li id="product_cat-68">
        <input value="68" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-68">
        <label class="selectit">Otros</label>
      </li>

      <li id="product_cat-65">
        <input value="65" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-65">
        <label class="selectit">Pañuelos</label>
      </li>

      <li id="product_cat-802">
        <input value="802" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-802">
        <label class="selectit">Para celulares</label>
      </li>

      <li id="product_cat-206">
        <input value="206" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-206">
        <label class="selectit">Pipas, tabaqueras y cigarreras</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="product_cat-266">
    <input value="266" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-266">
    <label class="selectit">Alimentos</label>
    <ul class="children">

      <li id="product_cat-267">
        <input value="267" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-267">
        <label class="selectit">Adornos para torta</label>
        <ul class="children">

          <li id="product_cat-270">
            <input value="270" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-270">
            <label class="selectit">Casamientos</label>
          </li>

          <li id="product_cat-271">
            <input value="271" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-271">
            <label class="selectit">Cumpleaños</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li id="product_cat-268">
        <input value="268" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-268">
        <label class="selectit">Cervecería</label>
      </li>

      <li id="product_cat-334">
        <input value="334" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-334">
        <label class="selectit">Mermeladas y dulces</label>
      </li>

      <li id="product_cat-281">
        <input value="281" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-281">
        <label class="selectit">Tortas decoradas</label>
      </li>

      <li id="product_cat-269">
        <input value="269" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-269">
        <label class="selectit">Yerba</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Wow, this is too close to what he wanted. But I really do not need to check all categories children when I check the parent category, but I see that if I comment a line in the code is solved.

Comment: Yes you can comment that line.

Comment: But if I remove the functionality mentioned before: If I uncheck the parent category, the child also should uncheck.

Comment: You can do that easily by adding a condition : if(!checkboxValue){
                $(this).closest("li").find(".children input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked",checkboxValue);
            }

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:

Now the solution is handling all parents until the root:

```
handleChildren = function() {
  var $checkbox = $(this);
  var $checkboxChildren = $checkbox.parent().find(".children input[type=checkbox]");
  $checkboxChildren.each(function() {
    if ($checkbox.is(":checked")) {
      $(this).prop("checked", "checked");
    } else {
      $(this).removeProp("checked");
    }
  });
};
handleParents = function(current) {
  var $parent = $(current).closest(".children").closest("li").find("> input[type=checkbox]");
  if ($parent.parent().find(".children input[type=checkbox]:checked").length > 0) {
    $parent.prop("checked", "checked");
  } else {
    $parent.removeProp("checked");
  }
  handleParents($parent);
}

$('ul.product_cat_list').find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(index, input) {
  $(input).on('click', handleChildren);
  $(input).on('click', function() {
    handleParents(this);
  });
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/diegopolido/040shgbg/4/

Comment: This halfway works. The bubbling of the checkmarks up to the parent only works for one nested level though. In your fiddle, checking _"Cinturones de hombre"_ also checks _"Cinturones"_ which is good. But as _"Cinturones"_ is a child of _"Accesorios"_, _"Accesorios"_ should also be checked. It should flow up the levels until you reach the top. The nesting effect is slighly off. See the other answer for clarification. When reviewing that example, try selecting a checkbox nested two levels deep.

Comment: So fork and improve it  ;)

Comment: I think you missed the point. The answer is technically incomplete. It doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: Fixed ;) now all parents is handling until the root

Answer (score 0):

I have added "indeterminate state checkboxes" based on Diego's code.

```
handleParents = function(current) {
  var $parent = $(current).closest(".children").closest("li").find("> input[type=checkbox]");
  if ($parent.parent().find(".children input[type=checkbox]:checked").length > 0) {
    if ($parent.parent().find(".children input[type=checkbox]:checked").length == $parent.parent().find(".children input[type=checkbox]").length) {
      $parent.prop("indeterminate", false);
      $parent.prop("checked", "checked");
    } else {
      $parent.prop("indeterminate", true);
    }
  } else {
    $parent.prop("indeterminate", false);
    $parent.removeProp("checked");
  }
  handleParents($parent);
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wyysoft/xu0ev6wp/

Answer (score 0):

Modification of Eric Wang's Code to work jQuery 1.6+ and a fix to prevent the handleParents calling itself forever.

```
handleChildren = function() {
  var $checkbox = $(this);
  var $checkboxChildren = $checkbox.parent().find(".children input[type=checkbox]");
  $checkboxChildren.each(function() {
  if ($checkbox.prop('checked')) {
     $(this).prop('checked', true);
  } else {
     $(this).prop('checked', false);
  }
 });
};
handleParents = function(current) {
  var $parent = $(current).closest(".children").closest("li").find("> input[type=checkbox]");
  if ($parent.parent().find(".children input[type=checkbox]:checked").length > 0) {
    if ($parent.parent().find(".children input[type=checkbox]:checked").length == $parent.parent().find(".children input[type=checkbox]").length) {
      $parent.prop("indeterminate", false);
      $parent.prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $parent.prop("indeterminate", true);
    }
  } else {
    $parent.prop("indeterminate", false);
    $parent.prop('checked', false);
  }
  if($parent.length >0){
    handleParents($parent);
  }
}
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ufoajkh7/